# Problem adding attribute options to configurable product via REST Api

Tags: magento2, api, magento-2.1.9

I have been following the Magento documents about API's.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#/

I am using this API:

> catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1

Using Postman I **POST** via API:

> web/rest/es/V1/products/attributes/sgi_test/options

With the body:

```
{
    "option": {
        "value": "12",
        "sort_order": 0,
        "is_default": true,
        "store labels": [
            {
                "store_id": 1,
                "label": "U"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And it returns me ***true*** but it's not giving me the ID.

What I am seeking for is the ID in order to save the product created into SAP. 
Could I use another API? Or modify this one and add a function to get the ID?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution on this? I am having the exact same issue on Magento 2.2.11

Comment: Hey bud, I honestly don't remember, it was a long time ago. Try browsing between the different methods, maybe there's a list method you can use to retrieve the ID.